# How to scale up pudding recipe 10x?

Tags: food-science, sugar, custard, pudding

I am trying to make a 10X recipe of a cooked pudding.  It uses flour and corn starch as a thickener.  I scaled up the ingredients proportionally, but it is not as thick.  Any recommendations on how better to scale the ingredients?  Is the sugar interfering with the gel?  Do I need to change the ratio of the thickeners? Should the proportions be different?  Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you scale up the size of your pan and/or the heat going into the pan?

Comment: ... or cook it in a few batches.

Comment: Original recipe was in a 3 qt sauce pan over 1 burner.  For the 10x I use a professional 20 x 22" roasting pan over 4 burners.  The larger pan let's me get more surface area for the increased volume.

Comment: I currently am cooking multiple batches, but since I need to make it often, at some point I really need something that is scaled up.

Comment: You could run 4 pots with doubled recipes to get 8x at one time. Try the recipe doubled and tripled and see how it comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling out a recipe is often more difficult than just "multiplying" the ingredients. In the Book [Ratio](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416571728) they have a chapter on Custard:

> The standard ratio is bedrock, 2 to 1; 16 ounces milk blended with 8
>   ounces (4 large) eggs will result in 24 ounces of an excellent
>   custard. Large eggs are about 2 ounces each, which makes custards easy
>   to manage without a recipe: a cup of milk and 2 eggs, or ½ cup of milk
>   and 1 egg. But 1 large egg will set three-quarters of a cup of milk
>   into a perfect custard. So, as with all ratios, and recipes, it can
>   vary. If you intend to turn the custard out and it needs to hold its
>   shape, stick with the basic ratio. Extra yolks are often added for
>   texture and richness. The quantity of sugar and the quantity of fat
>   also affect the final outcome. If you’re using a lot of sugar, you may
>   need to add a little more protein for structure. If you’re using only
>   heavy cream, you may need less.
>
> Ruhlman, Michael. Ratio (Kindle Locations 3475-3481). Simon &
>   Schuster, Inc.. Kindle Edition.

Simply doubling a recipe is usually pretty straight forward...the more you scale upwards the more 'out of alignment' your ratios become (particularly where eggs are involved).

Without your base recipe I have to warn 'your mileage' may vary' So be prepared to tweak it to your taste.

Comment: Yes, this is my concern exactly.  Thanks for the reference and insight.  This is an eggless recipe.  It roughly has a 1:1 wt. ratio milk:sugar.  It has a flour/cornstarch mixture to thicken.  The combo is about 20% of the amount of sugar (about 12.5% flour, 8% corn starch).  So to your note about protein, maybe I need to increase the amount of thickener.  Any idea or guess as to how much before one can taste the thickener? The scale of liquid is a gallon of milk. I've also considered reducing the sugar thinking that maybe it is interfering with thickening.  Any thoughts to either direction?